# How to interpret font-size of text from adobe XD?

Tags: css, adobe-xd

```
font: SemiBold 14px/17px Basier Square;
```

I am trying to copy styles of a text from Adobe XD and it shows me font-size as above, I am confused, should I interpret it as 14px or 17px?

Comment: 17px is the `line-height` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Font-size = 14px, Line-Height = 17px;
It is not Adobe specific, it's simple HTML definition
Reference: From Mozilla [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font#Syntax), we can understand that

> If font is specified as a shorthand for several font-related properties,

then-->

> line-height must immediately follow font-size, preceded by "/", like this: "16px/3"

Answer (score 0):

```
font: SemiBold 14px/17px Basier Square;
```

That would be

```css
.element {
  font-family: 'Basier Square';
  font-weight: 600; /* SemiBold */
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 17px;
}
```